# Is this valid SQL? Or is it breaking any MySQL rules?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is this valid SQL? The usage of `GROUP BY` as well, is it correct?

Also how can I sort the results by TOTAL?

Thanks

```
     SELECT packages.id          AS PPIIDD,
       Q_ALLOTMENTS.total   AS TOTAL,
       roomname,
       hotelrooms.room_id   AS RID,
       packages.description AS PDESC,
       hotelname,
       regionname,
       places.name          AS PLACENAME,
       destinationname,
       hotels.property_desc,
       hotels.hotel_id      AS HID,
       room_rates.high      AS ROOM_HIGH,
       packages.low         AS PLOW,
       hotels.startype,
       address1,
       address2,
       town,
       postcode,
       hotelrooms.room_id   AS RID,
       packages.type        AS PTYPE
FROM   packages
       INNER JOIN hotels
               ON hotels.hotel_id = packages.hotel_id
                  AND hotels.status = 'active'
       INNER JOIN allotments_new
               ON allotments_new.package_id = packages.id
                  AND allotments_new.day_date >= '2013-04-17'
                  AND allotments_new.day_date < '2013-04-18'
                  AND allotments_new.day_rate > 0
                  AND allotments_new.status != 'n'
                  AND allotments_new.minimum_number_of_nights <= 1
       INNER JOIN hotelrooms
               ON hotelrooms.room_id = packages.room_id
                  AND hotelrooms.status = 'active'
       INNER JOIN room_rates
               ON room_rates.room_id = hotelrooms.room_id
       INNER JOIN destinations
               ON destinations.destination_id = hotels.destination_id
       INNER JOIN regions
               ON regions.region_id = hotels.region_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN places
                    ON places.id = hotels.places_id
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Sum(day_rate) AS TOTAL,
                          allotments_new.status,
                          allotments_new.number_of_rooms,
                          day_rate,
                          day_date,
                          package_id
                   FROM   allotments_new
                   WHERE  allotments_new.day_date >= '2013-04-17'
                          AND allotments_new.day_date < '2013-04-18'
                          AND allotments_new.day_rate > 0
                          AND allotments_new.status != 'n'
                          AND allotments_new.minimum_number_of_nights <= 1
                   GROUP  BY allotments_new.status,
                             allotments_new.number_of_rooms,
                             day_rate,
                             day_date,
                             package_id) AS Q_ALLOTMENTS
               ON Q_ALLOTMENTS.package_id = packages.id
WHERE  hotels.hotel_id = '1875'
       AND packages.status = 'active'
       AND hotels.status = 'active'
       AND hotelrooms.status = 'active'
       AND maximum_number_of_adults_and_children >= '1'
       AND 1 = '1'
       AND 1 = '1'
       AND 1 = '1'
       AND 1 = '1'
       AND 1 = '1'
       AND 1 = 1
       AND 1 = 1
GROUP  BY ppiidd
ORDER  BY startype DESC
```

Comment: Try to run it...? I'm pretty sure MySQL will tell you if it doesn't like it.

Comment: I don't know, it's a lot to read. Does it execute?

Comment: If there's some reason that you don't want to execute the query, you can prepend EXPLAIN to it. This will validate the query without executing it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What exactly is your question? Does it work when you try it? If so, it's valid. If not, what exact errors are you having with it? This is not really a site for "Here's a whole bunch of SQL. I'm not going to try it, so please tell me if it will work" questions. We're happy to answer specific questions, but you have to ask them first. Voting to close as not a real question, because there's nothing being asked that we can answer here. The [faq] has some ideas on how to write questions here in a way that will get you answers. Good luck. :-)

Comment: It works fine in MySQL by MySQL is loose and it doesnt mean it is valid SQL. I basiclly need to know how to ORDER BY TOTAL DESC. Thanks Ken

Comment: There's a limit of one `1 = '1'` clause in each query or the person who ends up having to maintain this is automatically entitled to bitch about your code in [online forums](http://thedailywtf.com/).

Comment: You should always check to make sure 1 = 1. Always... it should be required in all "where" clause.

Comment: @sam You're laughing now, but when `1` does *not* equal `1` some day, who will be laughing then?

Answer (score 3):

Mysql has a special way of handling group by that AFAIK is not supported on any other database. Here it is:

Normally, the group by must list *all* columns that are not aggregated. But in mysql, instead of throwing an error, mysql's behaviour is to return one row, randomly selected, for each unique combination of the columns that *are* listed in the group by clause. As a matter of practicality, the row chosen is not random, but the *first* row encountered.

The answer is it's not an error, but the query may not return the results you expect.

---

As an aside, this feature is really handy for getting the first/last row based on some subset of the columns, for example to get the latest row for each item:

```
select * from (
    select * from mytable order by timestamp desc) x
group by item_id
```

The middle query makes sure rows are encountered in timestamp order latest first. The funky group by returns the first row encountered for each item_id, which is of course the latest.

Comment: +1 because "wtf, I didn't know that...."

Comment: MySQL does a lot of things for you automatically, like group on columns you haven't explicitly selected, or discard data that didn't fit into a field, you know, without telling you or anything.

Comment: How about ORDER BY TOTAL? OREDR in subquery doesn't work. What do you suggest?

Comment: @scotch read the addendum to my answer. At first i though it was the devil's work, but it's so handy :)

Comment: @benjaz in mysql Oder by is allowed in subquery :)

Comment: This sounds downright dangerous.

Comment: @Bohemian Wow that actually makes a really common (semi-complicated) query more simple. Theres a lot of cases where people want the highest value something for each category but want the actual entire row and not an aggregation.